# LSTM model is overfitting spx data?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Hello i create this model to predict future spx price, but results are too good to think i'm not overfitting.
python code here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/74124/97054.
can someone help me to understand if hyper-parameters are ok?

Thank you

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Please do not use links in asking questions -- they are strongly not recommended. Also, datascience.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask the data science questions.

Comment: These kind of question are off-topic, as they are not programming problems. Keep asking on the Data Science SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Davide, are you aware that LSTMs are not a good model for stock predictions? (at least if you are only using past stock data)

Think about this in a very simple way. If I tell you how the value of Coca Cola stock changed over the past ten years, can you tell me what will happen next month?

No, because the stock price is not directly related to it's prices in the past. If anything, the stock price is related to the emotions of people, which is why a tweet from the president can disrupt the entire market or a hybrid vehicle setting on fire can sink Tesla's stock.

Your data is over-fitting and changing hyper-parameters will not fix that. Proper stock predictions would need to utilize NLP for articles, social media, etc.

Comment: My first idea was to add several features (multivariate model) , not only price, but if my model overfits the data i thought it was useless because i would get the same results if i do not understand how to 'control' the overfit. Thanks for answer

Comment: I see. Yes, this is a common problem with using an LSTM. If you use it on test data, you'll probably end up with a flat line as the LSTM will always predict the value the preceded it. I don't have any better suggestion for you, other than learning more about deep learning models. I wish you the best in your continued search for a good model.